# XSLT won't select on a node for simple move-and-replace text() node script

Tags: xml, xslt

Separately on this site I've gotten great REGEX help (thanks Andreas!) to find these fields by hand.  But I wanted to preserve 100% of the original Emergency Services data, not edit the field to conform to the NEMSIS XSD as the REGEX workaround with manual subjective editing.

Accordingly, I'm trying to take any E09_05 or E09_08 element (Chief Complaint and Secondary Complaint, per the NEMSIS data dictionary) that is `string-length()` > 50 characters and `concat()` it to the beginning of the Narrative or E13_01 field.  I'd then be replacing these long complaints with a simple `<E09_05>See Narrative E13_01 for Chief Complaint</E09_05>` (same for E09_08, just "Secondary Complaint" instead).

Every single tag, text, and attribute otherwise in the souce XML must be passed through untouched (cf. the `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">` at the end of the script).  The only changes being to move the long complaint fields to their respective narrative for each `<Record>`.

Colleagues helped me work this script up.  They swear it works on their system, but I cannot get it to work on mine.  I've tried several xslt engines, including msxsl.exe (required in our environment), but also --just trying to get something to work and rule out a processor problem-- the one in Notepad++ XML Tools, the one in XML Copy Editor, as well as the online free one at freeformatter.com.  In  the end,  though, msxsl should be the one that works (not my choice ... it's a government thing).

As I've commented in the source and XSLT files below, I've tried relative XPath with descendant `//`, or absolute path, etc.  No luck.

Source XML (extensively stripped for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EMSDataSet xmlns="http://www.nemsis.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nemsis.org http://www.nemsis.org/media/XSD/EMSDataSet.xsd">
  <Header>
   <!-- SOME STUFF -->
   <Record>
<!-- LOTS OF STUFF -->
       <E08>
        <E08_08>2016</E08_08>
        <E08_10 Lat="42.63" Long="70.68" />
      </E08>
      <E09>
        <E09_04>-5</E09_04>
        <!-- XSLT SHOULD HIT ON THIS AS IT'S AN E09_05 WITH > 50 CHAR string-length() -->
        <E09_05>this one is too long Non-Emergency - PT IS BEING DISCHARGED FROM AGH AFTER BEING ADMITTED FOR FAILURE TO THRIVE AND ALCOHOL WITHDRAWAL</E09_05>
        <E09_11>-5</E09_11>
      </E09>
      <E10>
        <E10_01>-5</E10_01>
        <E10_03>-5</E10_03>
      </E10>
<!-- SOME IN BETWEEN STUFF -->
      <E13>
      <!-- xslt SHOULD concat() THE OVER-LONG E09_05 TEXT HERE AT THE BEGINNING -->
        <E13_01>A8 DISPATCHED TO AGH FOR A 66 Y/O MALE PT BEING DISCHARGED FROM AGH WITH UNSTEADY GAIT --DELETED FOR BREVITY --**A8 CLEAR, WITHOUT INCIDENT**. </E13_01>
      </E13>
    <!-- REST OF THIS DELETED TO SAVE SPACE -->
    </Record>

    <Record>     
     <!-- STUFF DELETED FOR BREVITY - AND THIS E09_05 BELOW SHOULD BE IGNORED BY THE XSLT AND PASSED THROUGH AS IS -->
      <E08>
        <E08_08>2016</E08_08>
        <E08_10 Lat="42.77" Long="70.61" />
      </E08>
      <E09>
        <E09_04>-5</E09_04>
        <E09_05>this length is okay</E09_05>
        <E09_11>-5</E09_11>
      </E09>
      <E10>
        <E10_01>-5</E10_01>
        <E10_03>-5</E10_03>
      </E10>
<!-- DELETED FOR BREVITY -->
      <E13>
        <E13_01>CC= Working as a P/B truck during major snowstorm, on scene, found pt c/o having a syncopal episode.     HXPI= Pt's girlfriend stated that the pt had been outside shoveling snow for approx 1 hour. --DELETED FOR BREVITY OF EXAMPLE </E13_01>
      </E13>
    </Record>
</Header>
</EMSDataSet>
```

Here is the XSLT -- the only thing in it that works is the first template to preserve empty tags as empty, not pairs without content (semantically equivalent, yes, but the NEMSIS XSD won't accept paired tags, only empty ones), and the last template which passes through the full source content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- THIS TEMPLATE I FOUND IN A WEB SEARCH TO KEEP EMPTY TAGS AS EMPTY TAGS, WHICH I KNOW ARE SEMANTICALLY EQUIVALENT, BUT THE NEMSIS.XSD WILL NOT ACCEPT PAIRED TAGS, ONLY EMPTY ONES FOR CERTAIN TAGS -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(comment() | processing-instruction() | *)][normalize-space(text()) = '']">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="@* | namespace::*">
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- REPLACE E09_05 FIELDS THAT ARE > 50 CHARACTERS WITH THIS "SEE NARRATIVE ..." REPLACEMENT -->
<xsl:template match="E09_05[string-length(.) > 50]">
    <E09_05>See narrative for Chief Complaint</E09_05>
</xsl:template>

<!-- DO THE SAME THING HERE FOR E09_08, I TRIED A FEW DIFFERENT PATH OPTIONS TO GET IT TO "HIT" AND NONE WOULD WORK, E.G., DESCENDANT AXIS //, ABSOLUTE PATH, ETC. -->
<xsl:template match="E09_08[string-length(.) > 50]">
    <E09_08>See narrative for Secondary Complaint</E09_08>
</xsl:template>

<!-- CONCAT THE OVERLONG E09_05 AND/OR E09_08 TEXT TO THE BEGINNING OF THIS E13_01 FIELD -->
<xsl:template match="E13_01/text()">
    <xsl:copy/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('ChiefComplaint:',' ', ../../../E09/E09_05[string-length(.) > 50])"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('SecondaryComplaint:',' ', ../../../E09/E09_08[string-length(.) > 50])"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity transform - pass through all other content complete and untouched/unchanged -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just another variation of the FAQ for XSLT/XPath 1.0 on how to match and/or select elements in the input which are in a namespace, to do that you need to declare the namespace in the XSLT with a prefix you can choose and then you need to use that prefix to qualify any element names in XSLT match patterns and XPath path expressions; with some clean-up to use `xsl:copy` to easily ensure copied result elements preserve the input namespace and some variables to clearly identify the elements you want to refer to and to only insert the text constants like `ChiefComplaint:` if there was an overlong entry you end up with

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:em="http://www.nemsis.org"
    exclude-result-prefixes="em"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- REPLACE E09_05 FIELDS THAT ARE > 50 CHARACTERS WITH THIS "SEE NARRATIVE ..." REPLACEMENT -->
<xsl:template match="em:E09_05[string-length(.) > 50]">
    <xsl:copy>See narrative for Chief Complaint</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- DO THE SAME THING HERE FOR E09_08 -->
<xsl:template match="em:E09_08[string-length(.) > 50]">
    <E09_08>See narrative for Secondary Complaint</E09_08>
</xsl:template>

<!-- CONCAT THE OVERLONG E09_05 AND/OR E09_08 TEXT TO THE BEGINNING OF THIS E13_01 FIELD -->
<xsl:template match="em:E13_01/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="e09_05"
      select="ancestor::em:Record/em:E09/em:E09_05[string-length(.) > 50]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$e09_05">
        <xsl:text>ChiefComplaint: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$e09_05"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:variable name="e09_08"
      select="ancestor::em:Record/em:E09/em:E09_08[string-length(.) > 50]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$e09_08">
        <xsl:text>SecondaryComplaint: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$e09_08"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexji2

Comment: Thank you!  Sigh ... I remember some 20 years ago banging my head on the desk and missing xmlns.  Arrrrggh ... I knew it'd be something like that ... but I kept missing it.   Thank you -- and EMS thanks you ...